# Simple POJO cannot be resolved in workspace

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code, classnotfoundexception

I have a Spring Boot SOAP service using cxf with a `@Service` that calls a `@Repository` that has a `JdbcTemplate`. Everything is autowired. I have created a model POJO class (PersonUdland) that represents the table in the database and it only contains getters and setters.

My problem is that I get a `The import dk.dxc.soapdemo.models.PersonUdland cannot be resolved to a type`. It is used in the repository and the service and it is not recognized in either class. I use VS Code and when I save a file or do `clean` and `package` using maven wrapper, the error shows. If I make a change in the service or repository file (where the error appears) and do `ctrl+z`, the error disappears. Another `ctrl+s` and the error is back. I tried to clean the Java Language Server Workspace. Nothing happens. Then I thought it could be VS Code that has a bug, so I  tried with Eclipse. Same error, but when I run `clean install` with eclipse's maven (not maven wrapper), no error shows. Neither in Eclipse nor VS Code. When I run the generated empty `contextLoads()`-test, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` and `ClassNotFoundException` on the `PersonUdland` model class.

When I build the application and run it locally, there are no problems though. The same for the build and deploy (with Ansible) Jenkins servers.

I have no clue what to look for and the error shows as a syntax error in the IDE's, so a Spring annotation should not do anything (I have tried adding `@Component` to the model class though) and `@ComponentScan` should not be used because it scans for annotated classes and  all folders are under the root java folder anyway.

My project structure looks like this:

```
project
│   pom.xml    
│
└───dk.dxc.soapdemo
│   │   SoapDemoApplication.java
│   │   ServletInitializer.java
│   │
│   └───service
│   │   │   PersonUdlandServiceEndpoint.java
│   │ 
│   └───models
│       │   PersonUdland.java
│   │ 
│   └───repositories
│       │   PersonUdlandRepository.java
│   │ 
│   └───config
│       │   ApplicationConfig.java
```

Service:

```
package dk.dxc.soapdemo.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

// "Cannot be resolved" error
import dk.dxc.soapdemo.models.PersonUdland;
import dk.dxc.soapdemo.repositories.PersonUdlandRepository;
import dk.skat.begrebsmodel._2016._01._01.*; // <-- generated from wsdl

@Service
public class PersonUdlandServiceEndpoint implements 
PersonUdlandSkattefritagelseSendServicePortType {
    @Autowired
    private PersonUdlandRepository personUdlandRepository;

    @Override
    public PersonUdlandSendOType getPersonUdlandSend(PersonUdlandSendIType request) {
        // "Cannot be resolved" error
        PersonUdland personUdland = personUdlandRepository.getPersonUdlandByPnr(request.getPersonCPRNummer());

        return response;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
package dk.dxc.soapdemo.repositories;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
// "Cannot be resolved" error
import dk.dxc.soapdemo.models.PersonUdland;

@Repository
public class PersonUdlandRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    // "Cannot be resolved" error on return type
    public PersonUdland getPersonUdlandByPnr(String pnrNumber) {
        Map<String, Object> resultSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(sqlQuery, pnrNumber);
        // "Cannot be resolved" error
        PersonUdland personUdland = new PersonUdland();

        //set fields on personUdland and return
    }
}
```

The model:

```
package dk.dxc.soapdemo.models;

public class PersonUdland {
    // Fields that are all Strings

    // Getters and setters
}
```

**Edit: Added db config**

The database is configured through `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://path:to/db
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
spring.datasource.tomcat.name=DBName
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=1
spring.datasource.tomcat.maxActive=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-connect=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

The db dependencies I use:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
    <version>db2jcc4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cisuz</artifactId>
    <version>3.69.24</version>
</dependency>
...
```

Comment: Can you also send your DB config class ?

Comment: @sevvalai I have added the configuration

Comment: You said `when I run clean install with eclipse's maven (not maven wrapper), no error shows`, which is also accessible in vscode and provided by extension **Maven for JAVA**. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried it, and it gives the same errors as using the wrapper and. I am supposed to use the wrapper anyway.

Comment: @Kikkomann I don't see the DB config class, however have your added the line to scan the model packages in the DB config?

Comment: @sevvalai I don't have a DB config class. I configure the db in the application.properties. As I understand it `@SpringBootApplication` contains `@ComponentScan` and it is in the root of the java packages, so it shouldn't be necessary to add anything for the model package to be scanned right?

Answer (score 0):

You should have @Entity and @Table annotation on entity class.

Comment: That didn't help and after adding it, the application won't run.

Comment: Can you add the full error (full stack trace)

Comment: https://github.com/Kikkomann/errors/blob/master/running_the_project.txt
It is the same stacktrace regardless if I add `@Entity` and `@Table` or not.

Comment: I think no issue in your code. You have to setup java development environment or other required environment on IDE. Follow the link. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project